# Groovy range function not working on large numbers

Tags: groovy, range

I have this fairly simple code:

```java
BigInteger bigNum = 600851475143

println 1G..bigNum
```

The result is a empty list (`[]`), Why is this the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely it returns empty list as you are trying to create array with the size `>` than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`

```
BigInteger bigNum = 600851475143

println bigNum -10 .. bigNum
```

> [600851475133, 600851475134, 600851475135, 600851475136, 600851475137, 600851475138, 600851475139, 600851475140, 600851475141, 600851475142, 600851475143]​

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the answer (though it does make my life a little harder :)